# How to toggle LED of ESP8266 in MQTT

Tags: python, mqtt

I am using MQTTLens to publish text using Python script. I have got a ESP8266 board which is connected to MQttLens  I can control LEDs by Publishing 1 & 0. But i want to control LEDs from a python script like when I type in terminal 1 it is ON and 0 it is OFF .

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
import time

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):

    if rc == 0:

        print("Connected to broker")

        global Connected                #Use global variable
        Connected = True                #Signal connection 

    else:

        print("Connection failed")

Connected = False   #global variable for the state of the connection

broker_address= "broker.mqtt-dashboard.com"
port = 1883
user = "xxxx"
password = "xxxx"

client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               #create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)   #set username and password
client.on_connect= on_connect                  #attach function to callback
client.connect(broker_address, port=port)          #connect to broker

client.loop_start()        #start the loop

while Connected != True:    #Wait for connection
    time.sleep(0.1)

try:
    while True:

        value = raw_input('Enter the message:')
        client.publish("xxxxx",value)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

     client.disconnect()
     client.loop_stop()
```

Comment: You've not actually stated what the problem is here. The Python looks OK at first glance (once the indentation is fixed), what isn't working?

Comment: This scripts work fine.What lines of code should i add in this code which will send commands via broker to control LED of my ESP8266 board.

Comment: Nothing (unless you want to add code to enforce that only 1/0 is published)

Comment: Why  i need this is beacuse  I have made a UI interface using   Kivy framework . What i  want is when i press the button LEDs should change states somthing like   https://mctouch.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/kivy-opengl-console-controlling-mbed-via-mqtt/

Comment: It's still not clear what you  are asking. Edit the question to include a lot more detail of the problem you are trying to solve or I'm going to vote to close this question.

Comment: In the picture when i type 1 and press publish LEd on ESP8266 is "ON" and when 0 is typed it is "OFF".
This same operation i want to run using  a script written in python ,
[DIAGRAM][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR408.jpg

Comment: Edit the question to add the details

Comment: Well i think i found out the solution.

Comment: If you have a solution feel free to add it as an answer as it may help others (and may help explain what the original problem was)